# Using systemd notify on behalf of another process

Tags: systemd

I am implementing a watchdog feature to one of my services using the `systemd`.I have a situation wherein I need to send a notification to `systemd` on behalf of another process. So, I used `NotifyAccess=all` to send the notification on behalf of another process, thinking there might be a privilege issue to write on to the socket. But, still, I fail to send the notification to the `systemd`. I used `--pid` option to send the notification as well here.

I am using `Ubuntu 21.10`, the desktop version.

Could you please help me here how can I send the notification?

Thanks & Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: Hello. It may be helpful to know what version and type of Ubuntu you are using? Desktop, Server or Core.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1399676/edit) and add which distro and version of Linux you are using.